# Should this request be GET or POST?

Tags: http, post, asp.net-web-api, get

My API accepts 2 parameters, product and quantity, and it returns a price.

At the moment this is a 'GET' request, which makes sense. But there are now new requirements to log every price that is returned in an audit table. This now feels like a POST?

### Question

What is/where can I find the criteria for determining whether a request should be made as GET or POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is some subjective, but I think I'll let the API as GET request. You're not creating or updating the price (your main entity), auditing it's just a side effect.

Also you can think, as a developer who doesn't know about the auditing process and consumes your API, getting information using POST can be weird.

Comment: You can get more information about Google API Design Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods

Comment: *"as a developer who doesn't know about the auditing process"* - this is a great point, I didn't think of looking at it from this perspective. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

GET -  It perform when you first time enter to page

POST - It perform when you make some actions(for example you will change data) on the page and after that you reload it